# C Program with getchar() and EOF

Tags: c, eof

Why does the program enter infinite loop when I input EOF (Ctrl-D)?

```
    #include  <stdio.h>
    
    main()
    {
            int c = EOF ;
    
            while(c==EOF)
            {
                    printf("input value c=%d \n",c);
                    printf("EOF=%d \n",EOF);
                    c = getchar();  //expect the while loop to pause here and wait for input
    
            }
    
            printf("the value of last input c=%d \n",c);
    
    }
```

When I enter any other character the program exits immediately as expected.
But when I enter EOF (Ctrl-D) I expect the program to reiterate within the while loop and wait for the next user input with getchar.

Update: I read the manual pages for the shell this program runs in
manpage for GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

```
Commands for Changing Text
       end-of-file (usually C-d)
              The  character  indicating  end-of-file  as set, for example, by ``stty''.  If this character is read
              when there are no characters on the line, and point is at the beginning of the line, Readline  inter‐
              prets it as the end of input and returns EOF.
```

I think what is happening is that when I enter EOF as input the shell no longer passes input to program so program just skips the line c=getchar(); and repeats the loop.
Any further insights will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding `clearerr(stdin);` at the start of your loop? I can't reproduce your problem (on Windows) but maybe, on your platform, the EOF flag prevents `getchar` from attempting further input operations.

Comment: What do you want to do? Once `getchar` returns `EOF` [from entering `ctrl-D`], it will continue to do so. After `getchar` [as Adrian suggested], if you do: `if (c == EOF) clearerr(stdin);`, it _will_ work as you're intending: if you then enter `j\n` [you _need_ the newline to get the kernel tty layer to send the chars], you'll get the `j`. It is _not_ the shell that is controlling input, it is the kernel tty driver/layer. But, why? The usual is: `while (1) { c = getchar(); if (c == EOF) break; process_char(c); }`

Comment: @CraigEstey "Once getchar returns EOF, it will continue to do so" does have a rare exception: When `EOF` returned due to input error, a subsequent call may not return `EOF` - depends on the error.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica For non-tty input, that's probably true. But, OP is talking about tty input and the only way [that I can think of] to get an error is to send a signal to the process or kill the containing terminal emulator. But, it's looking more like an XY problem. For OP: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: A more orthodox while loop would be `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { … }` with no need for `getchar()` inside the loop.  That doesn't do quite the same job, but it is probably more useful in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the program enter infinite loop when I input EOF (Ctrl-D)?

Once the file is closed due to OP's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, `getchar()` does not wait for anything and just returns `EOF` as the *end-of-file indicator* is set.

> 7.21.7.6 The `getchar` function
> If the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set and `getchar` returns `EOF`.

To make `getchar()` wait for another character, clear the *end-of-file indicator*.  Perhaps with `clearerr()` ([@Adrian Mole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65729804/c-program-with-getchar-and-eof/65729946#comment116214921_65729804)) which clears both the *error* and *end-of-file indicator*.

---

> when I enter EOF as input the shell no longer passes input to program so program just skips the line c=getchar();

I'd say the `getchar()`, when the *end-of-file indicator* is set, does not call the shell for more data and simply returns `EOF`.  Details are implementation specific.

Comment: clearerr(stdin) clears the end-of-file indicator . Program know works as expected.